# angular 2, get latest photos from instagram

Tags: angular, instagram-api

I am trying to get the 4 latest pictures from my Instagram account and display them in a component. 
I just want to display the photo, and link it to the post.

```
import {Component, Init} from '@angular/core'
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `...`,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
photos;

  constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.photos = this._jsonp.request('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN').subscribe();
  }
}
```

then in the template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let photo of photos">
   <a href="{{photo.link}}">
    <img src="{{photo.img}}"/>
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you getting your data in `this.photos` variable?

Comment: try `jsonp.get().map()` instead of `jsonp.request()`